# Using '#' end of openURL

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
let x = dpadtxt.text! + "#"
let url = URL(string: ("tel://23456712561,2#,\(x)"))!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

when I add `#` at the end of the string it gives me this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Apple URL Scheme reference [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) where you can read about how to work with telephone number encoding.

In that document you can read...

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but
>   not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if
>   a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt
>   to dial the corresponding phone number. If your app receives URL
>   strings from the user or an unknown source, you should also make sure
>   that any special characters that might not be appropriate in a URL are
>   escaped properly. For native apps, use the
>   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method of NSString to
>   escape characters, which returns a properly escaped version of your
>   original string.

You have to encode you number `String` with something like this

```
let phone: NSString =  "tel://23456712561,2#,#"

if let phone = phone.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
{
    print(phone)
}
```

Please, check if my `NSCharacterSet` is correct, cause I can't test it on a device right now.

Comment: OMG. Amazing. It worked. You saved my life. thank you. :)